# how to create unique sequence in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, sequence

How to create unique sequence number in MySQL?

The scenario goes like, that in `table1` the data say `"A"` in row1 can appear more than once.

So when it is first occurring a sequence no will be assigned to it, and the same will be assigned to it each time it appears again.

But the data `"B"` (say the next data entered) will have the next sequence no.

So i cant use auto_increment in this scenario. Say, i have to check the conditions c1 and c2 for this unique sequence no.

Looking for a stored procedure to implement this. Hope i am clear with my problem.

Comment: In situations like this, I make two tables. One for the describing the categories (a single A, B etc) and the other with the instances (as many A's, B's as needed). The auto_sequence would of course go into the former and the tables are connected by the sequence number or the category name.

Comment: @igelkott ... kind of thought of that...but it lead to data redendency.. and also there were problems when i wanted to access the data... which table to refer to  depending on the count(lead to more complexity)..so cameup with this scenario

Comment: My separation suggestion is generally to avoid redundancy. Of course, I don't know your data so maybe I misunderstood but check out "database normalization" in Wikipedia (eg) and see if it might apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `seq` (
    `n` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`n`)
);

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getseq$$

CREATE FUNCTION getseq() RETURN BIGINT
BEGIN
DECLARE r BIGINT;
    INSERT INTO `seq` (`n`) VALUES (NULL);
    SELECT MAX(`n`) INTO r FROM `seq`;
    COMMIT;
    RETURN r;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Concurrent transactions should be revised, but I think it would work, because indeed the mark of auto-increment is shared across transactions, but not the id resulting from the insert you made into the table.

Comment: glad it helped! I shall accept your upvote & answer as a reward